# Building a select query to isolate all nodes with a date greater than

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Here is a snippet of XML:

```
<AssignmentHistory Version="210002" DateLastPurged="2020-12-11">
    <W20190107>
        <Teaching>
          <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
          <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
          <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
        </Teaching>
    </W20190107>
    <W20190114>
        <Teaching>
          <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
          <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
          <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
        </Teaching>
    </W20190114>
</AssignmentHistory>
```

I realise that my use of `WYYYYMMDD` for the element name was not very clever. I designed the XML file when I was only learning XML / XSL and now see it not to be good.

The above is stripped down just to show what I need to show.

I know I can do a path query like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");
XmlNodeList nl = doc.SelectNodes("AssignmentHist/*/Teaching");
...
```

And it will return **all** of the `Teaching` elements in a `XmlNodeList`.

The XML file is sorted in descending date order and what I would like to do is use a query that will select all teaching nodes where the date is greater than a specified value. At the moment I have to:

- Iterate the complete list
- Get the name of the parent node (`WYYYYMMDD`)
- Strip the leading `W`
- Extract the `YYYY`, `MM` & `DD` components
- Build a `DateTime` object and compare the date of interest against `xxxx.Date`.

It would be nice if the single select query could put all of those out. But can it be done?

Comment: "...It would be nice if the single select query could put all of those out..." Are you talking about SQL Server `SELECT ...` statement?

Comment: can we assume you are in c#?

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer I tagged it c#. So yes.

Comment: yea just making sure, sry :)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I updated the question to make that cleaer. It is not SQL Server `SELECT`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, how about XSLT transformation to process input XML?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Could a dynamic translation be done in memory with just those elements? I would like to avoid needing a physical XSL file and external XML file. But if a dynamic XSL could transform just those bits into a new dynamic XML for query. If it is even worth it? The file is not huge and the existing c# code not overly complex. I just wondered if a xpath query was possible.

Comment: This will be much easier to do with linq to xml, instead of xpath.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Can you show me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clean method by using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xelement-class-overview) that is available in .Net since 2007.

It is a one liner with chained logic:

- Find all `<Teaching>` elements
- `Where` clause is going to the parent node, its name is converted to a string, "W" is removed, converted to DateTime data type and compared with a `DateTime` parameter dt.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2019-01-10");

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<AssignmentHistory Version='210002' DateLastPurged='2020-12-11'>
        <W20190107>
            <Teaching>
                <Name Class='1'>Brother 1</Name>
                <Name Class='2'>Brother 2</Name>
                <Name Class='3'>Brother 3</Name>
            </Teaching>
        </W20190107>
        <W20190114>
            <Teaching>
                <Name Class='1'>Brother 4</Name>
                <Name Class='2'>Brother 5</Name>
                <Name Class='3'>Brother 6</Name>
            </Teaching>
        </W20190114>
    </AssignmentHistory>");

    var xelem = xdoc.Descendants("Teaching")
        .Where(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Parent.Name.ToString().Replace("W", "")
            , "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > dt);
}
```

**Output**

```
<Teaching>
  <Name Class="1">Brother 4</Name>
  <Name Class="2">Brother 5</Name>
  <Name Class="3">Brother 6</Name>
</Teaching>
```

Comment: While using LINQ is the most elegant solution im my opinion as well, the question was how to achieve that by using an XPath query. Still, I'm upvoting this.

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer It is true that I specifically stated `xpath` but that was because I did not see there was alternatives. I appreciate all these responses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to go to any great lengths of manipulation here; your strings thankfully will sort alphamerically as they would numerically (W20200101 is greater than W20191231)..

```
//AssignmentHistory/*[name() >= 'W20190107']
```

To be clear, the reason I didn't put `/Teaching` on the end is because without it the result from the posted example is:

```
<W20190107>
    <Teaching>
      <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
      <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
      <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
    </Teaching>
</W20190107>
<W20190114>
    <Teaching>
      <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
      <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
      <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
    </Teaching>
</W20190114>
```

And with it the result is:

```
    <Teaching>
      <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
      <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
      <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
    </Teaching>
    <Teaching>
      <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
      <Name Class="2">Brother 2</Name>
      <Name Class="3">Brother 3</Name>
    </Teaching>
```

Because this data in the latter example is repeated/these Teaching nodes seemingly have nothing to tell them apart, I figured to leave the W nodes in because they provide identity. If you want just the Teaching nodes, use an xpath of:

```
//AssignmentHistory/*[name() >= 'W20190107']/Teaching
```

Comment: Alright, but don't you need to stitch `Teaching` into that path?

Comment: It depends if you need to tell the results apart? If you put `/Teaching` on the end you lose the W numbers, which presumably have some relevance?

Comment: The underlying XML file is not going to change. We are simply extracting data (specifically a list of names / class / date) items in a list that are future to the passed in date.

Comment: OK, so feel free to put `/Teaching` on the end.. The reason I didn't was because the way the question is posed, it repeats the `Brother=x` numbers, (the two `<Teaching>` blocks inside the W blocks are identical, so it looked like dropping the W numbers would mean they lost some vital aspect of their identity)

Comment: They are not identical because the two W nodes are different dates.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that if you put /Teaching on the end of the xpath, you lose the W nodes.. i.e. you lose the thing you *just said* makes them "not identical". I made an edit to explain

Comment: still its a nice solution, (but boring compared to manipulating :) ), ima upvoteing this against my own (stylish) answer

Comment: I will try tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a nice puzzle,

You could try that, it uses an XPath query and string interpolation (so don't forget the $):

```
DateTime searchDate = new DateTime(2019,01,14);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");
XmlNodeList nl = doc.SelectNodes($"//Teaching[xs:date(replace(substring(parent::*/name(), 2),'(\\d{{4}})(\\d{{2}})(\\d{{2}})','$1-$2-$3')) > xs:date('{searchDate:yyyy-dd-MM}')]");
```

I didn't try it in C# code though, so it might have syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, so that will pick all nodes greater than the test date?

Comment: ah shit no i skipped that haha. I just read " compare the date of interest against xxxx.Date." I'll give it some minutes trying to fix it. expect an edit or deletion then haha

Comment: No worries. I just reliased that I still have to create a DateTime in the end anyway for my returned array of items. But thanks for your efforts.

Comment: ah, greater or greater than or equal?

Comment: I will try tomorrow, thanks. The other answer is easier to read but I want to test this one too ... :)